# Can't import a property value while using a placeholder

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot.

I declared properties in an external file outside the classpath.

I added that to one of my XML files:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>file:///d:/etc/services/pushExecuterService/pushExecuterServices.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

However, I still get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'configuration.serviceId' in string value "${configuration.serviceId}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
```

I added a breakpoint in the `PropertiesLoaderSupport` class at this method:

```
public void setLocations(Resource... locations) {
    this.locations = locations;
}
```

I paid attention that this method invoked multiple times and in one of them I noticed the locations param populated with:

```
URL [file:/d:/etc/services/pushExecuterService/pushExecuterServices.properties]
```

However, I am still getting this error.

- I double checked in my project and I dont have any additional PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer beans(didnt check on external dependencies)
- I ran my app with hard code the params inside the xml I can see within spring-boot logs:

  ```
  2015-01-05 18:56:52.902  INFO 7016 --- [           main] 
  o.s.b.f.c.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer: Loading properties file from
  URL [file:/d:/etc/services/pushExecuterService/pushExecuterServices.properties]`
  ```

So I am not sure what's happening. any leads?

thank you.

Comment: One thing you should do is rewrite your title so it's a complete sentence, and fix up the spelling and formatting issues (though I only see a couple at first glance) in the question.

Comment: Just noticed you are using Spring Boot, you should just add your properties to the `application.properties` you are fighting the framework instead of working with it.

Comment: Yes but our company policy is having specific properties in external file located outside. why spring-boot would prevent me that?

Answer (score 5):

Spring Boot favors Java-based configuration. In order to add configuration properties, we can use @PropertySource annotation together with @Configuration annotation.

The properties can be stored in any file. Property values can be injected directly into beans using the @Value annotation:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:mail.properties")
public class MailConfiguration {
    @Value("${mail.protocol}")
    private String protocol;
    @Value("${mail.host}")
    private String host;
}
```

@PropertySource's value attribute indicate the resource location(s) of the properties file to be loaded. For example, "classpath:/com/myco/app.properties" or "file:/path/to/file"

But Spring Boot provides an alternative method of working with properties that allows strongly typed beans to govern and validate the configuration of your application: @ConfigurationProperties

See this blog post with an example of using @ConfigurationProperties: http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/09/using-configurationproperties-in-spring.html

For the @PropertySource example you can check this article: http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/09/testing-mail-code-in-spring-boot.html

Comment: But you can use @PropertySource for files outside the classpath as detailed within my question?

Comment: Yes. As I wrote in the answer: "@PropertySource's value attribute indicate the resource location(s) of the properties file to be loaded. For example, "classpath:/com/myco/app.properties" or "file:/path/to/file"

Comment: ok one more thing I forgot to mention. I am injecting the property to applicationContext.xml and not into any java class. I tried @PropertySource("file..) still same error

Comment: I don't know your conf, but I made a test. I defined PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer static bean in Application class that reads some external file and used it in xml configuration. I imported this configuration to the application using: @ImportResource("classpath:some-config.xml") and everything worked just fine. Maybe this will give you some thoughts.